# 'No experienceId or projectId found' when attempting to use getExpoPushTokenAsync() on iOS

Tags: push-notification, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, expo-notifications

I'm creating an expo react native app that needs to be able to send push notifications to users. Since this app will be running on both iOS and Android, we're planning on using Expo's Push Notifications service.

However, whenever I attempt to use `Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()`, I get the following error:

```
No experienceId or projectId found. If one or the other can't be inferred from the manifest (eg. in bare workflow), you have to pass one in yourself
```

To the best of my knowledge, I have set up both Firebase Cloud Messaging and Apple Push Notifications, and linked them to my expo project on https://expo.dev. So far I've only managed to test this on iOS, so I'm unsure if it occurs on android as well.

Answer (score 5):

For Expo SDK 47 and up:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
const projectId = Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId;
const expoPushToken = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
  projectId
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a very simple fix. I was getting confused, as I thought it was referring to my firebase project's ID.

Fixed it by changing my code to:

```js
Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({projectId: "<EXPO-PROJECT-ID>"} )
```

You may also be able to specify the project ID somewhere in your app.json file.